# asp.net Web Service, a list containing a list

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net web service (.asmx) running on our server, it basically returns a result object which contains a list of users. The structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getUsersResponse xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/">
      <getUsersResult>
        <userList>
          <clsUser>
            <firstName>string</firstName>
            <lastName>string</lastName>
            <idNumber>int</idNumber>
          </clsUser>
          <clsUser>
            <firstName>string</firstName>
            <lastName>string</lastName>
            <idNumber>int</idNumber>
          </clsUser>
        </userList>
        <faultResponse>
          <faultOccurred>boolean</faultOccurred>
          <faultDescription>string</faultDescription>
        </faultResponse>
      </getUsersResult>
    </getUsersResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This works fine, but I would like to add a list to my `clsUser` class. So I would like to change it from this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

[Serializable]
public class clsUser
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int idNUmber
}
```

To this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

[Serializable]
public class clsUser
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int idNumber

    public List<clsExtraData> extraDataList;
}
```

Where `clsExtraData` contains a few strings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

[Serializable]
public class clsExtraData
{
    public string description;
    public string data;
}
```

So I would expect my structure to look something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getUsersResponse xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/">
      <getUsersResult>
        <userList>
          <clsUser>
            <firstName>string</firstName>
            <lastName>string</lastName>
            <idNumber>int</idNumber>
            <extraDataList>
               <description>string</description>
               <data>string</data>
            </extraDataList>
          </clsUser>
          <clsUser>
            <firstName>string</firstName>
            <lastName>string</lastName>
            <idNumber>int</idNumber>
            <extraDataList>
               <description>string</description>
               <data>string</data>
            </extraDataList>
          </clsUser>
        </userList>
        <faultResponse>
          <faultOccurred>boolean</faultOccurred>
          <faultDescription>string</faultDescription>
        </faultResponse>
      </getUsersResult>
    </getUsersResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But instead I get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getUsersResponse xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/">
      <getUsersResult>
        <userList>
          <clsUser>
            <firstName>string</firstName>
            <lastName>string</lastName>
            <idNumber>int</idNumber>
            <extraDataList xsi:nil="true" />
          </clsUser>
          <clsUser>
            <firstName>string</firstName>
            <lastName>string</lastName>
            <idNumber>int</idNumber>
            <extraDataList xsi:nil="true" />
          </clsUser>
        </userList>
        <faultResponse>
          <faultOccurred>boolean</faultOccurred>
          <faultDescription>string</faultDescription>
        </faultResponse>
      </getUsersResult>
    </getUsersResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Our web service users will design their clients around this web service structure, if it's showing up with the `<extraDataList xsi:nil="true" />` how will they know what fields to expect in the `extraDataList`? How can I get my web service structure looking as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you post the WSDL im pretty sure there is a link explaining the values and fields in extraDataList